# Loopback filter objects in an array by substring of its element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, loopbackjs

I have an array of objects. I want to filter it in such a way that it only returns the objects which element value matches a particular filter. Like if the element value contains some string, that object will be there in the returning array.

For example if I have an array like this:

```
[
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
]
```

I want it to filter by the name element and only return the object containing "F" in the name element. Like it'll return only the following

```
[
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
]
```

how do I do that in loopback angular sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the methods [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const data = [{"name": "Ford","models": ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]},{"name": "BMW","models": ["320", "X3", "X5"]},{"name": "Fiat","models": ["500", "Panda"]}];
const filterByStr = 'F';
const result = data.filter(obj => obj.name.includes(filterByStr));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the following code, it uses [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
let arr = [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
]

arr = arr.filter(function(val){
    return val && val.name && val.name.match(/F/g);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is run a loop through your array and check whether the condition is getting satisfied or not.

Hope this helps.

```js
var arr=[
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
console.log(arr.length);

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
if(arr[i].name.startsWith("F")){
  Object.keys(arr[i]).forEach(function(key){
    alert(arr[i][key]);
  })
  }
}
})
```

Comment: But won't it slow down the process?

Comment: As compared to the above answers, yes! @Ani